# invalid initialization of reference of type

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

So I have this code and I have a problem with passing the argument into the function. When I compile I get the following error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Point&' from expression of type 'const Point*'

```
struct Point
{
    int x,y;
};

void printPoint(const Point& p)
{
    cout<<"The X-coordinate is = "<<p.x<<"\nThe Y-coordinate = "<<p.y<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    const Point p1 = {3,4};
    printPoint(&p1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&pi` is of type `Point*` (it's the address of that object), use: `printPoint(p1);`

Answer (score 1):

References are implicit. You do not need the `&`. In fact, that makes it a pointer (a `const Point*`, which is not implicitly convertible to a `const Point&`). Just do `printPoint(p1);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    const Point p1 = {3,4};
    printPoint(p1);
}
```

`&p1` gives the address of `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

this takes reference

```
void printPoint(const Point& p)
```

but you pass a pointer

```
printPoint(&p1);
```

so, use this one:

```
   printPoint(p1);
```